# How to turn on break when the exception type is user unhandled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nullreferenceexception

During debugging a NULL Ref Exception I accidentally unchecked the box `Break when this exception type is user-unhandled` in the exception popUp. How can I turn this back on?

I've looked at debug-> exceptions but dont see null ref mentioned

Comment: @John-Can I help any further on this? What ever happened with your issue?

Answer (score 6):

In the IDE, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Using the Search bar in the top right of the window that appears, search for
`NullReferenceException`
You will see:

[image]

---

Or, you can try "Restore defaults":

[image]

---

If you are having trouble testing that you're managing the right exception, try throwing an exception and interacting with the check box (off and on) like shown below. If **ON** then `break` here, if **OFF** then do not `break`:

[image]

Additionally refer to [Managing Exceptions with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)

Comment: @John I've added more information and a resource link in my Answer. I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.3, so my screenshots might differ a little.

Answer (score 0):

FYI...
Ctrl+Alt+E is equivalent to Debug, Windows, Exception Settings.